# rows concatenate in pandas dataframe -new version

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation, data-manipulation

I have following table.

```
import pandas as pd
# Define the input data
data = {
    'ID': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3],
    'count': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2],
    'priority': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,4,3,1,2,3,4,4],
    'item': ['A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D','D','C','A','B','C','D','D'],
    'c': ['XX','XX','XX','XX','YY-SS','YY','YY','YY','YY-SS','YY','YY','YY','XX','XX','XX','XX','ZZ','ZZ','ZZ','ZZ','ZZ','ZZ','TT-SS','ZZ','ZZ','ZZ','ZZ']
}

# Convert the input data to a Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

I need to transform this input as you can see in below output example: enter image description here
[image]

If you have any ideas please share. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you explain the logic in words to avoid having us to guess it?

Comment: sort by priority, groupby([id,count]), concatenate items and the first `c` within group?

Comment: the concatenation must be done on the basis of the 3 variables count,priority, item/ for the priority variable, sorting is also needed

Comment: @QuangHoang that was also my guess, but OP should better make this explicit

Comment: @Romeo how do you choose which `c` to keep? first one?

Comment: yes, the first one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate):

```
out = (df
   .sort_values(by='priority') # optional
   .groupby(['ID', 'count'], as_index=False)
   .agg({'item': '-'.join, 'c': 'first'})
   .assign(FINAL=lambda d: d.pop('item')+'-'+d.pop('c'))
   .drop(columns='count')
)
```

Output:

```
   ID          FINAL
0   1     A-B-C-D-XX
1   1  A-B-C-D-YY-SS
2   1  A-B-C-D-YY-SS
3   1     A-B-C-D-XX
4   2     A-B-C-D-ZZ
5   2         D-C-ZZ
6   3  A-B-C-D-TT-SS
7   3           D-ZZ
```